# Outputting specific values of a variable to a word document/power point from R

Tags: r

Had a question for you all.  I want to output specific variable results calculated in R in to a word document template. The word document is a monthly report that have the same variables in it but only the actual values change depending on the month. That is, I want to populate certain place holders of variable values based on my calculation in R then output them into a word document or even powerpoint slide. In SAS it would be a substitution "&variable".

For example in the word document or power point slide:

This month the amount of exposed people were &exposedthismonth where as the last month this many people were exposed &exposedlastmonth.

Is there such a function and export code that would allow me to do this in R?

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: Have you looked at `R Markdown` as an option? You can create a Word document and use inline code for your variable results within your template report.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I'll take a look at that. Do you know by any chance if I can use R markdown in a power point document?

Comment: Yes...take a look at: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004672913-Rendering-PowerPoint-Presentations-with-RStudio

Comment: That's great! thanks